# Calling a method three times the most basic way you can

Tags: java

I want to know if there are basic ways to call a method multiple times. I am not allowed to use for, if, or else statements. I am suppose to write a method called test 1 and test 2, which calls the increase speed and decrease speed by 3 times. If anyone can offer me suggestions, I would appreciate it.

**Requirements**

increaseSpeed. The increaseSpeed method should add 10 to the speed
field each time it is called.

reduceSpeed. The reduceSpeed method should subtract 10 from the speed
field each time it is called.

write a method called test1 that calls increaseSpeed three times.

write a method called test2 that calls reduceSpeed three times.

program:

```
 public void increaseSpeed()
   {
      speed += 10;
   }

   public void reduceSpeed()
   {
      speed -= 5;
   }
   public void test1(){

   }

   public void test2(){

   }

}
```

Comment: `while` .......... .?

Comment: Before you ask on SO, you [should do some research of your own first](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 4):

You could simulate a `for` loop with a `while` loop:

```
public void test1() {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 3) {
        increaseSpeed();
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Or, if you aren't allowed to use loops at all, you could just call the `increaseSpeed` three times:

```
public void test1() {
    increaseSpeed();
    increaseSpeed();
    increaseSpeed();
}
```

Comment: or even `while (i++<3) increaseSpeed();`

Answer (score 3):

We can also get more creative (a.k.a. pointless):

This first example requires Java 8, but it's a glorified FOR loop. You can replace 'forEach' with a map() or filter() that has an ignored output or one of the other Java stream processing items if you have an aversion to the word 'for'.

```
private static void test1() {
    IntStream.range(0, 3).forEach(
            i -> increaseSpeed()
    );
}
```

This second example uses a switch + recursion because you also didn't mention anything about the 'switch' statement.

```
private static final int INITIAL_COUNT = 2; // 3 - 1
private static int numTimes = INITIAL_COUNT;

private static void test2() {
    switch(numTimes) {
        case 0:
            numTimes = INITIAL_COUNT;
            break;
        default:
            numTimes--;
            test2();
            break;
    }
    reduceSpeed();
}
```

Note that if you tried to submit either of these to a code review, you'll be rejected unless the project is run by a joker that doesn't care about code quality :)

Answer (score 2):

```
public void test1(){
    increaseSpeed();
    increaseSpeed();
    increaseSpeed();
}

public void test2(){
    decreaseSpeed();
    decreaseSpeed();
    decreaseSpeed();
}
```

For more general "solutions" and hacks have a look at these: [C: Looping without using looping statements or recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564953/c-looping-without-using-looping-statements-or-recursion) and
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/33196/loop-without-looping.

Answer (score 1):

You didnt mention `while loop` is prohibited, i assume it is okay to use it:

```
int i = 0;
while(i<3){
    increaseSpeed();
    i++;
}
```

Alternatively, you can either use `do-while loop` to implement your requirement or invoke the method 3 times..

Answer (score 0):

Using the given methods, the most effective and simple way would be to invoke it 3 times in a row:

```
public void test1() {
   increaseSpeed();
   increaseSpeed();
   increaseSpeed();
}


public void test2() {
   decreaseSpeed();
   decreaseSpeed();
   decreaseSpeed();
}
```

A more flexible approach is using a recursive invocation, as described below:

```
public void test1() {
   increaseSpeed(3);
}

public void test2() {
   decreaseSpeed(3);
}

private void increaseSpeed(int numTimes) {
   if (numTimes == 0) {
       return;
   }

   increaseSpeed();
   increaseSpeed(numTimes-1);
}

private void decreaseSpeed(int numTimes) {
    if (numTimes == 0) {
        return;
    }

    decreaseSpeed();
    decreaseSpeed(numTimes-1);
}
```

Going a little bit beyond the question, if these tests model a real use case it probably is a good idea to review methods increaseSpeed() and decreaseSpeed() to prevent these multiple invocations.

Answer (score -1):

Your test1 method should be recursive and it should take an Integer as parameter which will be the number of calls you want to make
So basically you should have something like this:

```
public void test1(int nbcalls) {
  if (nbcalls-- > 0) {
     increaseSpeed();
     test1(nbcalls);
  }
}
```

and you call you method like this :

```
test1(3);
```

You should do the same with test2(...) method

Comment: OP: I am not allowed to use for, if, or else statements.